# Qual a diferença entre Int32 e int no C#?

Tags: c#, variáveis, tipagem

No C#, utilizar `String` ou `string`, `Int32` ou `int`, entre outros, não tem diferença, em tese. Alguém sabe se essa diferença gera algum impacto no desempenho de aplicações de alta complexidade?

Comment: Aqui tem um pedaço da resposta.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: Se não me engano está questão já existe no site.

Comment: De qualquer forma a resposta é: não faz a menor diferença. `int` é um apelido dado pelo C# ao tipo `System.Int32`, assim como ocorre entre `string` e `System.String`.

Comment: Logo vi porque não achei essa pergunta: o título é bem diferente do que a pergunta que estava na minha cabeça. Mas lá explica exatamente o que eu precisava saber: o compilador que faz a tradução desses _aliases_, ou seja, esse trabalho não fica para a máquina que vai executar o código. Por isso não gera impacto.

Answer (score 1):

`Int` e `Int32` = são sinônimos, o que difere é que `int32` fica mais explicito o `32bits` para quem for ler o código.

`string` é um alias para a classe `String` ou seja não há diferença, se você usar um ou o outro.

Resumindo: Não afetará em nada você usar ou outro, não haverá impacto no desempenho.